# How to connect custom USB device to iOS (already a MFi licensee)

Tags: ios, external-accessory, mfi, lightning

I am looking for an USB to Lightning adaptor that enables me to connect to a custom USB device in iOS that my company is producing.
The Apple Camera Lightning adaptor is only good for the "Picture Transfer Protocol" and some midi accessory. 
Since we want to use our devices in iOS we became now MFi Licensees.
But I am not sure how to proceed from there on.
How does one get raw USB data transfer on iOS? Will we need to develop our own adaptor and then use the  ExternalAccessory framework?
I'd appreciate it if anyone can help me out here.
Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you will need to work with Apple to get your device MFi certified and include an Apple identification chip.  You can then provide a lightning cable interface to your device

Comment: Thx! You mean an authentication chip like the one that is in apple's Lightning connectors? Instead of equipping our devices with such a chip (which would result in an all-new PCB design), wouldn't it be smarter to just make a lightning to USB adaptor that has this auth chip integrated?

Comment: I don't know all of the technical details as I am not an MFi licensee but as I understand it you need to add an MFi chip that you license from Apple.  This is similar but different to the lightning cable chip.  You could package this chip into a lightning to USB adapter.